# write a verilog for D FF

Tags: verilog, sequential, flip-flop, register-transfer-level

[image]

I want to write a behavioral verilog code for a FF with the following characteristics as shown in the picture.

```
module DFF ( D, CK, RN, Q );
input  D, CK, RN;
output reg Q;

always @ (posedge CK)
begin
if ( RN==1'b0 )
  Q <= RN ; 
if ( RN==1'b1 )
     Q <= D ;
if RN
```

I DONT KNOW WHAT TO WRITE HERE

```
end

    );
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

From your function table, RN seems to be treated as an asynchronous input.
In that case, `negedge RN` should also be added to the sensitivity list.
The remaining is the same as @Serge's answer.

```
always @(posedge CK or negedge RN)
    if (RN == 1'b0)
        Q <= 1'b0;
    else
        Q <= D;
```

Comment: Could I have written the condition here as if (! RN) instead of if (RN == 1'b0) to have the same output?

Comment: Yes. `(RN == 1'b0)`, `(! RN)` and `(~RN)` for 1-bit wire RN are identical.

Comment: One last thing, how do I know that I have to use negedge RN? Why negedge?
I don't see anything in the truth table showing sensitivity to negedge..sorry might be a dumb question..

Comment: Your truth table says Q is 0 whenever RN is 0.  This means you need to reset Q as soon as RN gets 0, that is `negedge RN`.  This is an idiom frequently used in Verilog for asynchronous resets and worth remembering.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to write there. It is easier, like the following:

```
always @(posedge clk)
   if (RN == 1'b0)
       Q <= 1'b0;
   else
       Q <= D;
```

The only way the Q can be changed is at the posedge of clk. So, your last row in the table is fulfilled here.

The rest is obvious, and you almost got it in your code.

You can use RN as rhs in your code, but it limits flexibility and usually constants are used there.

Comment: Thank you.

From what I understand, the last row states that when RN=1 for falling edge CLKs the output will be unchanged.

I want to understand why is it "RN"? Does it stand for Reset - negative? There should be a negatively edge triggered concept here somewhere? I took this from a manual so I am confident the term "RN" must mean something.

Comment: it is just a name of a variable. You probably guessed right for the abbreviation. ResetNegated looks like a possibility. And yes, there is a concept of `negedge` as well.

Comment: But how so? negeedge isn't doing anything in this case right? that's why it feels like I am missing something.

Comment: Sorry I am having a hard time to understand how this last case is captured by this code.

Comment: according to your table, negedge is supposed to do nothing. The old value og 'Q'should be preserved. This is exactly what is done in simulation: only the `posedge` is used for simulation of this block, as specified in its sensitivity list. The block just does not react to the negedge at all. Synthesis tools recognize this style and synthesize a hardware ff.

Comment: Do you agree with Hiroto Kagotani 's answer?

Comment: Yes, it looks like an `asynchronous` reset, because the first row in the table does not depend on the clock edge. Otherwise it would've been specified. So, Hiroto is correct. My example shows a `synchronous` reset.